# jQuery droppable/draggable not applying hoverClass (includes codepen)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I'm having is part of a larger app that I'm working on but I've replicated a non-working example in this codepen:

http://codepen.io/evanhobbs/pen/oEIKr/

In a nutshell I have a sidebar that can open/close and a list of items in it that I want to be droppable with jquery. When dragging over the items it should apply a hoverClass (as a background color) so the user knows where to drop. I've found a couple things:

1. If the sidebar is already open when I start dragging it works perfectly, ie the hoverClass is added.
2. If I do what I would like which is to start with the sidebar closed and open the sidebar when the user starts dragging, the hoverClass is not applied (though when I drop the item the drop works) UNLESS I drag off of the window and back first or drag to almost the edge. If I do this it works.

I'm tried to figure it out but I'm at a loss as to what's happening. I assume it has something to do with the sidebar animating out while dragging...

Comment: What web browser are you using?  I'm running Chrome and I find that if in scenario 2, if I hover over the first item the hoverClass appears to work.

Comment: @user3507600 His issue is that when the sidebar is shown by starting the drag, the `hoverClass` is not shown on the `<li>` tags until he drags the handle out of the screen and then back in. I'm able to reproduce this in Chrome

Comment: @Martin, I see; I misread it as it didn't work at all unless the sidebar was open first.  That said, it could have something to do with the way the sidebar is being displayed.  I changed from using animate to directly changing the CSS and don't see the issue anymore (same is true for setting `$.fx.off = true;`).  Maybe there's some existing knowledge about animate not checking onHover?

Comment: I changed the codepen so that the sidebar animates with CSS transitions. The issue still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. One idea I had was that on init draggable/droppable calculates the position of the elements and then only recalculates if it receives some sort of event by the mouse leaving the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely, we can still make it work the way it is, **IF** we go out of the `droppable` area and come back, but that is not what we want when we try to make an usable interface. So the matter is that when we start to drag the `droppable` seems not to be expecting that the `draggable` will already be hovering.

Luckily for us, `draggable` elements can be started with `refreshPositions` option, which when set to `true` will calculate the position in every mouse move, following the docs:

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-refreshPositions

> If set to true, all droppable positions are calculated on every
>   mousemove. *Caution: This solves issues on highly dynamic pages, but
>   dramatically decreases performance.*

Basically what we need to do is start the `draggable` with this option:

```
$('.drag-me').draggable({
    cursor: 'pointer',
    cursorAt: { top: 5, left: 0 },
    delay: 30,
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: 'clone',
    start: openSidebar,
    stop: closeSidebar,
    refreshPositions: true //added line
});
```

**Updated CodePen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lmFuH

Comment: That works! How did I miss that option? -- apparently I have to wait 24 hours to award the bounty so I'll do it tomorrow. Thanks...

Comment: hehe not really hard to miss actually, we were looking for the problem in the droppable when we had an option in draggable, I'm glad it worked!